# Scrapy FormRequest How to check if URL is needed

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and in general web tech.

While working on a scrapy example to perform auto login. I came across 1 field , referrer url . I am wondering when do i need to this.

```
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url='www.myreferrer.com', #when do i need this ???
            formnumber=1,
            formdata=self.data['formdata'],
            callback=self.after_login
        )
```

I tested with and without it and it works in both instances.

I understand that referrer url is for security but how do i determine from html code that i need or dont need this ? 
**ADDON**
The following html form required the url to be defined  :

```
    <form id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="https:///myshop.com/login/index.php?route=account/login">
        I am a returning customer.<br>
        <br>
        <b>E-Mail Address:</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <b>Password:</b><br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <br>
        <a href="https:///myshop.com/login/index.php?route=account/forgotten">Forgotten Password</a><br>
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a class="button" onclick="$('#login').submit();"><span>Login</span></a></div>
                  </form>`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class FormRequest(Request):

# delete some code here

    @classmethod
    def from_response(cls, response, formname=None, formid=None, formnumber=0, formdata=None,
                  clickdata=None, dont_click=False, formxpath=None, formcss=None, **kwargs):
    url = _get_form_url(form, kwargs.pop('url', None))


    def _get_form_url(form, url):
        if url is None:
            return urljoin(form.base_url, form.action)
        return urljoin(form.base_url, url)
```

if the `url` is empty, it uses `form` tag's action attribute to get the URL.

if the `url` is not empty, then it use the URL you give to it.

the `base_url` comes from the `response`.

```
def _get_form(response, formname, formid, formnumber, formxpath):
    """Find the form element """
    root = create_root_node(response.text, lxml.html.HTMLParser,
                            base_url=get_base_url(response))
```

so, when the action attribute does not exist or the login requests is not sent to the action URL, you need to pass the argument.

Comment: Can i say that if a valid form action=www.xxxx.com or action= /check/a.php is provided i should include url ?

Comment: @sean not, you do not need to, because `FormRequests` will do that for you

Comment: hi, i came across 1 case that must have the url defined . Please see my question edit